# Changing Apple ID's

Tags: apple-id, music

I have been using my parents Apple ID for a few years now to buy music and apps but now I am going to college and I don't think they want me to continue buying music and other stuff with their money. If I switch over to my apple ID on ITunes and my IPhone, will I lose all the music that I have on my phone.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. The stuff you already have under your parents account stays. Using you new apple id you can now purchase new stuff (without deleting the old stuff). All you do is switch the accounts.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask them to set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060), and then get them to invite your new Apple ID to the Family.

On the organizer iOS device, go to Settings > iCloud > Family and invite via Apple ID.

That way you can access all the content they (or you with their Apple ID) have purchased.

You can decide wether you want to [share](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201085) your purchase history with them, or hide specific items.

---

You will probably have to download apps and music again —I haven't tried it myself. Please tell us if that is not the case.

Comment: It think this is your only option because all content you download/buy is registered with an apple ID, when switching to another apple id, you have to download/buy everything (music and apps) again